# Barplot show only specific names (dates) in x axis

Tags: r

I am very new in using R and I have an issue with the x-axis in barplots.

Some example

```
 t<-seq(as.Date("2014-04-09"), as.Date("2014-10-09"), by="days")
 c<-sample(0:100,184, rep=TRUE)
 x<-data.frame(t,c)
 rownames(x)<-x[,c(1)]
 x<-subset(x,select=c(2))
 par(las=2)
 barplot(t(x))
```

As you can see, the date on the x-axis is not very nice. I want to display only some dates as it is true with las=1 but with the orientation of las=2. I tried to create a new object from the dates to get the names from that, but i was not able to do so. Maybe there is a way in the barplot or in making a new object for the names.

Thanks for your help

SOLUTION 1:

```
plot(t,x$c,type="h")
```

EDIT: The plot() solution works fine. but what if I need to have stacked Bars like in the new example?

```
 t<-seq(as.Date("2014-04-09"), as.Date("2014-10-09"), by="days")
 c<-sample(0:100,184, rep=TRUE)
 f<-sample(0:100,184, rep=TRUE)
 x<-data.frame(t,c,f)
 rownames(x)<-x[,c(1)]
 x<-subset(x,select=c(2,3))
 par(las=2)
 barplot(t(x))
```

Comment: If you create a vector of the names you do want (which you have not yet done) and then intersperse them with values of `""`, you can pass that to the `names.arg` parameter of barplot. You should realize that your `t`-data-object is different than the `t`-function and that when type `t(x)` you are using the function: transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Does this do what you want?

```
plot(t,x$c,type="h")
```

[image: plot]

(I assume that you don't *really* want to display a time series as a barplot and that this is just an example. For a time series, you'd usually do `type="o"`.)

EDIT: To get a *stacked* barplot, you can do the following - first plot the lower parts of the bars from `x$c`, keeping enough vertical space via `ylim` and using thicker lines with `lwd=3` so we can actually see the difference between the colored bars:

```
plot(t,x$c,type="h",lwd=3,ylim=c(0,max(rowSums(x))))
```

Then add the upper parts of the bars using the `lines()` function. For this, you need to specify a vector of x values. Since each bar will be vertical, we just use two copies of `t`. Then you need a vector of y values for the lower and upper end of the vertical lines. The lower end is `x$c`, and the upper end is `x$c+x$f`. We need to intersperse both the x and y vectors with `NA`s so the vertical lines are not joined together by diagonal lines. I find it easiest to just create three-row matrices using `rbind()`, where the last row is `NA`. (Below, I use `as.vector()` for clarity - it's not needed; `lines()` will convert the matrices into vectors by itself). Finally, we specify line thickness and color:

```
lines(as.vector(rbind(t,t,NA)),
  as.vector(rbind(x$c,x$c+x$f,NA)),
  lwd=3,col="gray")
```

[image: barplot stacked]

A word of advice: it's not a good idea to give your data structures names that conflict with R functions. For instance, you have a vector of dates `t`, but there is a function `t()` (which transposes matrices - you actually use that one). You also have `c`, which conflicts with the function `c()`. This will confuse both you and people who would like to help you here. Call your data structures `foo`, `bar` and `baz` in [time-honored fashion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Do you know a way to perform the same task if I want to generate stacked Bars like in the new example?